# Database schema for different groups of users in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, schema

I'm building a meteor app where I would like segmented groups of users to access the database. For example say I have products where:

```
products = new SimpleSchema({
  name: String,
  price: Number
})
```

but I have 2 companies using my app.  How would I keep their products seperate?  I was thinking something like

```
products = new SimpleSchema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  company: String
})
```

Only subscribing to the products for which the users company matches.  However, this feels clunky and has potential to publish the wrong products for a user.  Is there a better way to do this in Meteor?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [partitioner](http://atmospherejs.com/package/partitioner).

Comment: Thanks this looks like it may be what I need.